# Using of Loops then If and Else

Tags: java

I have a ToString() method I need to run but need to use loops instead of if and else statements. How should i do it?

```
public String toString() 
    {

        if (collectedDots == 0)
            return "Player[]"+"("+x+","+Math.abs(y)+")";
        else if (collectedDots == 1)
            return "Player["+"*"+"]"+"("+x+","+Math.abs(y)+")";
        else if (collectedDots == 2)
            return "Player["+"**"+"]"+"("+x+","+Math.abs(y)+")";
        else 
            return "Player["+"***"+"]"+"("+x+","+Math.abs(y)+")";

    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to use loop here. Switch case would be a better option to use in this case

Comment: _How would I do it?_ It's about printing a specific number of characters.  Give it a thought.  After all, it's _your_ homework.

Comment: @ankhuri `switch` is not ideal, because (1) it limits the number of `collectedDots` to the highest `case` in your switch, and (2) it makes you repeat essentially the same concatenation code several times.

Comment: for fun, `for(;condition;){statment; break;}` works as an if statement but never needed

Comment: First off, use a temp for `Math.abs(y)` to remove that clutter and let you see more clearly what you're doing.

Comment: OMG.....IS SO a place for HOMEWORK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a loop that produces a string of `collectedDots` asterisks:

```
String asterisks = "";
// Here is your loop. It iterates "collectedDots" times
for (int i = 0 ; i != collectedDots ; i++) {
    // Append an asterisk to the string "asterisks"; I assume that you know how to do that
}
```

With `asterisks` string in hand, the rest of your `toString` becomes trivial:

```
return "Player["+asterisks+"]"+"("+x+","+Math.abs(y)+")";
```

Comment: Append an asterisk to the string "asterisks"; no idea

Comment: @user3562745 Well, `asterisks = asterisks + "*"` will do it - you've used string concatenation `+` in your code, so I assumed that you know how to append a character to a string.

Comment: `i != collectedDots` is not good design. While it works, it isn't as clear as `i < collectedDots`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use switch instead of `if`

```
switch(collectedDots )
{
case 0:        return "Player[]"+"("+x+","+Math.abs(y)+")";
case 1:        return "Player["+"*"+"]"+"("+x+","+Math.abs(y)+")";
case 2:        return "Player["+"**"+"]"+"("+x+","+Math.abs(y)+")";
default:         return "Player["+"***"+"]"+"("+x+","+Math.abs(y)+")";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spent more time looking at your out put.

Did your teacher teach how to print the following pattern in class?

(nothing)

A

AA

AAA

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
        stringBuilder.append("*");
    }
}
```

Comment: No i want taught that append??

Comment: those are the behind the scenes and efficient use of `str+="*";` though that could be used too